# Android - Failed to initialize Monitor Thread: Unable to establish loopback connection

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to run a android application from eclipse on my android phone. It has been working for last 3-4 months. Suddenly stopped working since y'day.

I have tried multiple options mentioned in various other threads on stackoverflow including
1. Disabling Teredo interface
2. Adding "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" to eclipse.ini and ddms.bat
3. Stopping / Starting adb server. Starting / stopping eclipse etc.

Further observations
1. Running ddms.bat from command prompt detects my phone. However, phone is not detected under eclipse AVD manager or running ddms from eclipse.
2. Virtual emulator I have created in android opens OK from within eclipse.

Comment: user714965, as I said, I have tried the options mentioned in various SO threads. However, I am still not getting eclipse to detect my phone. The cmd options for ddms, adb devices are correctly detecting my phone. Also, I tried a driver update, but still no luck from eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue resolved. My anti-virus firewall was blocking my android phone from being recognized.
Had to disable the firewall and things are working now.

Cheers.